# Solving for height

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The volume of a cone is defined as
$$v=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$
where $r$ = radius and $h$ = height. My question is how do i solve for $h$ without any further information? I have tried to isolate $h$ by first dividing both sides of the equation by $h$ and then dividing both sides of the equation by $v$ but end up with $1/h$ and cannot find a way to isolate $h$. Can i get some pointers towards isolating the variable $h$? 
Thanks

Comment: If $\frac1h=e$ then $h=\frac1e$

Comment: Is e eulers constant or just an arbitrary variable?

Comment: $e$ stands here for "expression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply multiply both sides for 3 and divide both sides for $\pi r^2$ getting
$$h=\frac{3v}{\pi r^2}$$

Comment: Thanks man, cant believe i didnt think of that, my problem was not multiplying out the right side so i couldnt see that option

Answer (score 1):

There are two more things you're overlooking.

- The equation $p = q$ means exactly the same thing as the equation $q = p$
- The equation $\text{answer} = h$ is exactly as good at determining $h$ as the equation $h = \text{answer}$.

I presume the reason you divided by $h$ was to get it on the left hand side of the equation, but that makes things more complicated than necessary:

- You can just reverse the equation to get $h$ on the left hand side
- You could work to isolate $h$ on the right hand side instead

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have an equation $$a = bc$$ and you want to solve for $b$, just divide both sides by $c$ (and swap the LHS and RHS): $$b=\frac{a}{c}.$$

In your specific case, you have $$v = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h,$$ divide both sides by $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2$, giving you 
$$h = \frac{v}{\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2} = \frac{3v}{\pi r^2}.$$